# after update "the disk drive / is not ready yet or not present?"

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, update-manager, via

I've been messing around and I feel like I'm just opening a can a of worms.  Not sure If I'm getting closer to solution and I feel like I'm just discovering more problems and I'm not sure where to start.

I got a dpkg error and couldnt fix that
A UUID error

I don't think I'm connected to the internet when I'm not in one of the OS.

I'm freaked out because I can't access a major portion of the drive and this is the only place with pics of my kid.  Yeah I know don't scold me please.

Comment: We need *way* more information to be able to help. We need to know exactly what has happened, as well as you can tell us. In particular, if you've done anything in the Terminal, please select all the text in the Terminal and *edit your question*, adding it (you can use the `<$>` tool in the Ask Ubuntu editing toolbar to make it appear correctly). We need to know what happened before the "not ready" error happened, and what triggers it. Does it happen right when you turn your machine on? What was the `dpkg` error exactly? What did the UUID-related error say? What's "not in one of the OS" mean?

Comment: Also, *if* you need to recover data you believe may be lost, it's imperative you shut down the newly installed system right away and not use it. You can run from a live CD *provided that swap is disabled*. See [the guidelines here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery). Once booted into an Ubuntu live CD system, you can `sudo fdisk -l` in a Terminal window (Ctrl+Alt+T) and **edit your question** to provide the full output (format it with the `&lt;$&gt;` tool so it appears correctly). That should show what partitions there are, and facilitate knowing if data recovery is needed.

Comment: Please edit this question with the information Eliah requested, fail to do so will probably lead to having this question closed. If it is closed please create a new one with all the info needed, or edit this one and flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: after the upgrade, i get that message also, "the drive for '/tmp' is not ready yet/ press 's' to skip mounting or 'm' to fix manually".
it shows on the plymouth loading screen.
i don't respond to it-- everything seems to work fine.

Comment: i can't relate the title of your post to the rest of your post, however.  the post confuses me.

Comment: Leighton, I'm glad everything works fine for you. I've stared at the screen for hours (off and on) and it never became "fine" here. I will respond to the other replies as soon as possible. I'm in the process of trying to backup up data I'm afraid to lose.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

press <kbd>m</kbd>  to go to "Manual Recovery".
then type these commands:

```
mount -o remount, rw /
dpkg --configure -a
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had that problem while upgrading from 10.04.4 to 12.04.1 and found a possible solution in [rcampi's advice in ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1747835):

*It could be several things, but maybe the problem is due to the update didn't finished properly. If it is your case, try the following:
Press 'M' when asked to try to solve the problem manually.
In the console write the following, to remount / disk in Read&Write
`mount -n -o remount,rw /`
To finish the upgrade write
`dpkg --configure -a`
It could take several minutes.
Then reboot. 
Let me know if it works out*

It didn't work for me, but apparently helped quite a few people.

Comment: I was able to boot with a live CD and access the data in my home folder, so I figure you should be able to do the same and at the very least save your pictures.

Comment: Yes thanks I've managed to move everything onto an external drive.  I've now formatted the internal, partitioned it in the desired way, and installed 12.04.  I'm trying to move everything back to my home folder but running into new issues.  I've already asked a question related to that here.  This can be closed or moved or whatever.  A solution at this point isn't going to help me but it might help someone else.